# How to search a name with apostrophe in java struts framework

Tags: java, search, struts2, apostrophe

I am working in Java struts framework. When I tried to search name with apostrophe(For eg. O'connor) ,receiving no match result found error in the screen.But for without apostrophe(Oconnor), displaying details for the O'Connor.

This is the string declaration.

```
String name= StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(LastName);
```

Will **StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4** escape the apostrophe? or i need to modify the code to escape the apostrophe from the name.

Comment: You might want to read the javadoc for escapeHtml4(), or in doubt write an unit test verifying your desired behaviour

Comment: Thanks Gyro.Shall i run unit testing in eclipse.